# I want to bold a json data with css, how can I do this?

Tags: css, json, d3.js

Hi everyone based on [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999) example from Mbostock, I would like to bold specific text from JSON file

Can I set properties to my JSON such as:

```
> {"name":"AI.AI","size":3812,"properties":[{"style":"bold"}],"imports":[]}
```

It looks like the properties are not recognized and from CSS I can't control anything.

Maybe all of this is useless, can I simply directly add style to a JSON file?

Comment: Checkout highlight.js, https://highlightjs.org/

Answer (score 2):

Ok finally I sorted out

The JSON need to have the "type" attributed:

```
{"name":"AI.AI","size":3812,"type":"bold","imports":[]},
```

then in the JavaScript we return the style attribute:

```
node = node
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("dy", "0.31em")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.y + 8) + ",0)" + (d.x < 180 ? "" : "rotate(180)"); })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.key; })
    .style("font-weight", function(d) {return d.data.type; })
      .on("mouseover", mouseovered)
      .on("mouseout", mouseouted);
```

Hope it helps for those who have the same issue.